# react dispatch function after useSelector variable available

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to dispatch a function after useSelector function get called.

This is my code

```
 const profile = useSelector(
    ({ x}) => x.profile,
  );


  useEffect(() => {
     dispatch(fetchX(y, setXStatus)); // this is getting called before profile is available 
  }, [dispatch,y]);
```

The issue is when dispatch(fetchX(y, setXStatus)); getting executed profile variable is not properly set.Is there a way to run fetchX after profile is set.

Comment: If you need `profile` to be available for the useEffect, put it in the dependency array. If you are using eslint, it should be throwing an error.

Comment: @evolutionxbox so if i add profile as a dependency will fetchX won't getting called until profile is available ?

Comment: No, but it will re again when `profile` gets updated. It's not guaranteed to be defined.

Comment: @socialgamer - What do you mean by "is available"? `useSelector` grabs the current state synchronously. Is `profile` starting off `null` (or similar) and then getting set by some other action?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  yes it start with null.And updated by another action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "after useSelector function is called" you mean "whenever `profile` changes," you need to add `profile` to the dependency array. If `profile` can be `null` (or similar) and you need a profile before you can do the `dispatch`, you'll need a guard.

Something along these lines:

```
const profile = useSelector(
    ({ x}) => x.profile,
);

useEffect(() => {
    if (profile) { // <−−−−−− Guard
        dispatch(fetchX(y, setXStatus));
    }
}, [dispatch, y, profile]);
//               ^^^^^^^−−−−− Dependency
```

**Note,** though, that this effect callback will be called **every time** `dispatch`, `y`, or `profile` changes. `dispatch` probably never changes, but I don't know about `y` or `profile`.